# How to rename a file in all git branches

Tags: git

Is it possible to rename a file in all GIT branches older than 6 months?

I have tried few ways but I am curious to know if there is any command to do this.

Comment: What is a "branch older than 6 months"? Commits have dates; branches don't. So what is being measured here?

Comment: I mean a file should be renamed in all branches which got created 6 months ago

Comment: Why do you need to do it?

Comment: Note that files are not in *branches*. Files are in *commits*. Each commit has a snapshot (a full copy of *every* file, which is what you see if you check out that commit) plus some metadata: the name of the person who made the commit, for instance, and the date of the commit. No existing commit can ever be changed, but new commits hold new snapshots (usually re-using almost all the *data* from an old snapshot, and those are then de-duplicated) and new metadata.

Comment: Please state clearly what you want to do _in terms that are meaningful for Git_. A Git branch has no notion of when it got created. Branches don't have dates. And the concept "a file in a branch" is utter nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

loop over all branches, check if a branch older than 6 months contains the file, if does rename and commit.

```
for k in $(git branch | sed /\*/d); do 
  if [ -z "$(git log -1 --since='6 months ago' -s $k)" ]; then
    git show :./file_to_be_renamed > /dev/null  2>&1
    if [ "$?" -ne 0]; then      
      git checkout $k
      mv file_to_be_renamed my_new_file
      git add my_new_file
      git commit -m "rename old file"
      git push
    fi
  fi
done
```